# Using CsvTypeProvider's AsyncLoad method

Tags: f#

I am trying to get data using CsvTypeProvider's AsyncLoad method, and having trouble returning data asynchronously. Here's is my method:

```
member internal this.loadCsvFromUrl() =
        async {
            let! data = Stocks.AsyncLoad(urlForDates ticker startDate endDate) 
            return data }
```

When trying to access the "Rows" value in another area of my program, I receive the following error on `first`:

```
let msft2014Url = new ChartingAndComparingPrices.CsvConstructor("MSFT",    (DateTime(2014, 1, 1)), DateTime.Now)
let msft2014 = msft2014Url.loadCsvFromUrl // Returns Async<CsvProvider<..>>
let first = msft2014.Rows |> Seq.minBy (fun itm -> itm.Date) // Error: The field, constructor, or member 'Rows" is not defined.
```

Of course, running Synchronously, I am able to call `msft2014.Rows`, and obtain the data, but I am unsure how to return Rows from an async call.

Would appreciate a push in the right direction. Thank you!

EDIT:
Fixed. Here's my refactor:

```
type GetCsvData() = 
    //get data for msft
    let getFirstClose = async {
        let msft2014Url = new ChartingAndComparingPrices.CsvConstructor("MSFT", (DateTime(2014, 1, 1)), DateTime.Now)
        let! msft2014 = msft2014Url.loadCsvFromUrl()//.loadCsvFromUrl
        let first = msft2014.Rows |> Seq.minBy (fun itm -> itm.Date)
        let firstClose = float first.Close
        return firstClose
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make something asynchronous, you can only call it from other asynchronous computations. Since your `loadCsvFromUrl` method is now asynchronous (contains body wrapped in the `async` block), it also returns an asynchronous computation of type `Async<T>`. This means that you can only call it by blocking (using `Async.RunSynchronously`) or from another asynchronous computation:

```
async {
  let msft2014Url = new ChartingAndComparingPrices.CsvConstructor("MSFT",    (DateTime(2014, 1, 1)), DateTime.Now)
  let! msft2014 = msft2014Url.loadCsvFromUrl 
  let first = msft2014.Rows |> Seq.minBy (fun itm -> itm.Date)  
  return first }
```

By wrapping the code in `async` and adding `let!`, we now get the value `CsvProvider<...>.Row` from the asynchronous computation.

Now you need to figure out how to start this new top-level asynchronous computation though. Typically, you can run multiple of them using `Async.Parallel` and then block using `Async.RunSynchronously`, or you'll have some computation that eventually does something with the result (like prints it) and this one you can then spawn in the background using `Async.Start` or `Async.StartImmediate` (if you're doing something with GUI).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I'm using the async call within a type though. Thus getting "Unexpected identifier in member definition" when wrapping those lines in the async keyword. Is it possible to use async within a type, or do I need to move these lines out to the module?

Comment: It should work inside members of a type too - sounds like an error you'd get if you miss `=` or some other easy-to-make syntactic mistake.

Comment: Yep, I just needed to put it inside of a let binding. Refactored code added to the question. Thank you!